# Finding the first sentence with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find the first sentence of a textarea. At the moment, I can find the first full stop and turn it into an array with `.split()`, but what happens if they use an exclamation mark, question mark, etc?

I have the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/mzzq4/

```
var l = $('p');

$('textarea').keyup(function(){
var t = $('textarea').val();
var t = t.split('.');

l.text(t[0]);

});
```

Is there a way this could be made more fullproof, so it splits at either:

`.`, `.`, `!`, `?`, `enter/linebreak`

Any help would be great,

Comment: scan the text first to determine the sentence deliminators first. then split on my one, augmenting an overall array!

Comment: Sounds like a job for a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes . there is a way.

Do this:

```
var t = t.split(/[\?!\.\n\r,]/);
```

I'm using `regex`, in which I'm using character class to define what to be split upon.

Comment: It splits on any non-word character (`\W`) or new line, not a good approach if space is treated as non-word character

Comment: This is great. Unfortunately the first example seems to cut off when the user presses the space bar / it is a space

Comment: @tmyie, check it out now. Use my second regex ;)

Comment: Thanks! Accepted. What was the problem?

Comment: My first regex also matched spaces ;-/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var t = t.split(/[\n\r\!\,\.\?]/);
```

or add any more reqular expressions.

Comment: How about a linebreak (so if they press the enter button?)

Comment: @tmyie: `\n\r` covers line breaks.